# Styling INDIVIDUAL cells in GAS FlexTable ...impossible?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, flextable

It appears there is no way to style individual cells (to, say, change the background color of a header row, for example) within a GAS FlexTable. Is that correct?

The only methods I see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_flextable) are .setStyleAttribute() and .setStyleAttributes() both of which operate on either the entire application or the entire flextable as the object.

Furthermore, I see no methods that return an individual cell or subset of cells from the flextable such as a .getCell() or .getRow().

Therefore, am I correct in concluding that there is no way at this time to set the style of an individual cell in a GAS flextable? (Sorry if the answer to this question is an obvious, “There is no way to do it.” But I figured I had better check with the experts first before giving up.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting style to individual cell is done with:

method setStyleAttribute(row, column, attribute, value) - Sets a CSS style on a cell of this FlexTable.

You have to scroll down to the **second** occurence of setStyleAttribute on the FlexTable page. Since the HTML anchor is #setStyleAttribute for both methods you always get the first.

A getCell method would not be useful as a flextable cell is no widget.

There is also a setStyleAttributes(row, column, attributes) method ...

Answer (score 2):

setWidget is expensive

I pull out about `500X12` table in flextable and found use setText is at least twice times faster.

Then again, I also can not figure out how to change font size in flexTable while calling setText. The background, font color etc worked, but not font size.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way to do this. Instead of using FlexTable.setText() to set the contents, use the FlexTable.setWidget() instead. 
And you can add a label and style it however you want to and each label can have its own style

Comment: But setting the style attributes of a <div> in a <td> - this is what you are proposing - will have a different results from setting the style attributes of the <td> directly.